# Android Listview.getChildAt() points to two items

Tags: android

I have an activity that has a single listview in it with enough items to extend of the page.

I want to set a certain listView item at position i to a different drawable.

To go this I use the line of code..

```
listView.getChildAt(selector).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_button_shape_pressed);
```

There is a very confusing problem going in. This line of code is setting two listView items to the specified drawable.

When i = 0 item 0 and item 11 are set to that drawable. It turns out that when I call this line of code with i both item i and item i+11 are set to that drawable. This is rather baffling. Then to mix EVERYTHING when I start the activity in landscape, it is a different second listview that gets set to that drawable. And in certain scenarios when I change from portrait to landscape, the current highlight listview item on screen will change to a different one.

WTF is going on with the listview class? Are the indexes to it children constantly pointing to different things?

Here is my entire activity.

```
public class SelectorActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView;
private int selector;
private boolean set;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selector_layout);
    set=false;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras!=null)
    {
        selector=extras.getInt("selector");
    }

    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.selector_layout);

    //set the string array for the listview
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.sounds_array, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    listView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_background);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    highlightSelected();



}

//this method will highlight a selected listview once that listview is drawn
private void highlightSelected()
{
    if(!set)
    {
        new Thread(
                new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        boolean trigger=true;
                        while(trigger)
                        {
                            if(listView.getChildAt(selector)!=null)
                            {
                                set=true;
                                trigger=false;
                                listView.getChildAt(selector).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_button_shape_pressed);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            ).start();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

ListViews recycle their children. While drawing itself, the ListView will create a new view for every visible child. When you scroll, it will then re-use the last view that became non-visible (scrolled off the screen) as the next view in the list. That is why it's a different view index in landscape and that is why it would probably be a different view index on a device with a different screen size.

The solution should be to reset the view background in the Adapter's getView() method.

Additionally, touching views on anything other than the UI (main) thread is a bad practice. Check the selected item index in the getView() method and set the background right there. You'll also need to handle the case where the selected index changes (unless it never changes after this activity is created) by iterating over visible views in the listview and setting their backgrounds to the appropriate values.

```
        // Must be final to use inside the ArrayAdapter
        final int selector = extras == null ? -1 : extras.getInt("selector");
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
                this,
                R.array.sounds_array,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View newView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                // set the background according to whether this is the selected item
                if (position == selector) {
                    // this is the selected item
                    newView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_button_shape_pressed);
                } else {
                    // default background for simple_list_item_1 is nothing
                    newView.setBackground(null);
                }
                return newView;
            }
        };
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are suggesting as a solution, sorry.

Comment: This is confusing. What am I supposed to pass as convertView and parent when I call this method? All this did was give me a blank screen lol.

Comment: Nothing. You never call this method. It's a method that the ListView will automatically call for you every time it adds a view, so all you have to do is override it with your customized steps.

Comment: Well with this code above my listview is totally empty. and I changed the null to a different background in else block.

Comment: I also realize this solution will not work because I need to be able to change the selected one when it is click too. Why does listView not have a simple method that returns a view at position? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Because while you may have 100 items in the list, the ListView only has (in your case) 10 Views. Ever. The 11th view is actually the 1st view recycled because it's no longer visible. The 12th view is actually the 2nd and so on. The getView method of an adapter is what prepares the view to be displayed. It's at this point where you can retrieve the _data_ that corresponds with the current index and prepare the view according to that data. What you return from this method is the view that will be displayed. Understanding and implementing Adapters isn't a solution it's _the_ solution.